# How to delete selected text from textbox in c#(SWF)

Tags: c#

I try to do a notepad in c#,
I have some problems at delete function,
I want to delete selected text...

```
private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    int a;
    a = textBox1.SelectionLength;
    textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.SelectionStart,a);
}
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Remove` will return the truncated string, so you just need to reassign to the `TextBox`:

```
private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    int a = textBox1.SelectionLength;
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.SelectionStart,a);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use SelectedText like this :

```
textbox1.SelectedText  = "";
```

Comment: you are correct given all the information of the question this would work, i up voted :)

Comment: However i would use string.Empty instead of the ""